# Woocommerce wc_session_expiring difference to wc_session_expiration filter

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, woocommerce

What is the difference between the two filters `wc_session_expiring` and `wc_session_expiration` in WooCommerce? The filter is used in [woocommerce/includes/class-wc-session-handler.php](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-session-handler.php) in the function `set_session_expiration()`.

My object is to expand the storage time of the WooCommerce cart.

Comment: You should ask over in the WooCommerce support forums